# Use a Variable String Filter in a Function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr, panel

I have a panel dataframe with the values of several countries.

| Country | Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Austria | 1956-01-01 | 1.5 |
| Sweden | 1956-01-01 | 1.2 |
| UnitedKingdom | 1956-01-01 | 1.3 |
| Austria | 1957-01-01 | 1.6 |
| Sweden | 1957-01-01 | 1.0 |
| UnitedKingdom | 1957-01-01 | 1.8 |

I would like to write a function that filters out a variable country and Britain to be able to make comparisons between them on a graph.

```
PubHaus <- function(df, Nation) { 
    df %>% 
    filter(Country == {{ Nation }} | Country == "Unitedkingdom" ) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Value, color = Country)) + geom_line(size = 1.2) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + geom_vline(xintercept = as.POSIXct(as.Date("1948-01-01"))) + 
    labs(title = "Gross Public Housebuilding")
} 

PubHaus(Combined, Sweden)
```

However when I pass this code I obtain the error

```
Error: Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.
i Input `..1` is `Country == Sweden | Country == "Unitedkingdom"`.
x dims [product 532] do not match the length of object [1180]
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I imagine the error is something to do with not being able to define the Nation variable as a string. However for obvious reasons putting in

```
filter(Country == "Nation"
```

Would not return a country.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong and how I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

We could convert to string with `as_string` after converting to symbol as the input is unquoted.  In addition, `%in%` would be more useful for more than one element as a general case

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
PubHaus <- function(df, Nation) { 
    df %>% 
    filter(Country %in% 
      c(rlang::as_string(rlang::ensym(Nation)),  "UnitedKingdom" )) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Value, color = Country)) + 
    geom_line(size = 1.2) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0) + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = as.POSIXct(as.Date("1948-01-01"))) + 
    labs(title = "Gross Public Housebuilding")
}
```

-testing

```
PubHaus(Combined, Sweden)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
Combined <- structure(list(Country = c("Austria", "Sweden", "UnitedKingdom", 
"Austria", "Sweden", "UnitedKingdom"), Date = structure(c(-5114, 
-5114, -5114, -4748, -4748, -4748), class = "Date"), Value = c(1.5, 
1.2, 1.3, 1.6, 1, 1.8)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```